# How can I update data with Eloquent without id in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When I want to update the `FaqTrans` database, but this datase have two primary key (faq_ida and lang) `$table->primary(array('lang', 'faq_id'));`. so I don't need a `id` column with auto_increment.

However, when I use the following code to update the database, the error message hint me there is no `id` column.

```
$faq_trans = FaqTrans::where('faq_id','=',$faq_id)->where('lang','=',$lang)->first();
$faq_trans->lang  = Input::get('lang');
$faq_trans->body  = Input::get('body');
$faq_trans->title = Input::get('title');
$faq_trans->save();
```

error message

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: update `FAQtrans` set `body` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where
>   `id` is null) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'adfadaaadfadaa', 1 =>
>   '2013-07-04 11:12:42', ))

and when I added an `id` column, the code works fine...

are there any way can I update the database without ID column ?

Comment: did you set the primary key in your model

Comment: I tried to set the primary key in model, but it seem can't set two primary key at once (composite key), like `protected $primaryKey = array('lang''faq_id');`

Comment: You might have to use `->update(array('column' => 'value'))` instead of using save.

Comment: `->update(array)` is not works for me, I can only use `save()` and the document use `save()` to update data too..

Comment: did you try setting only one primary key

Comment: I've created a pull request that tries to implement this important but missing feature: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/1891

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel / Eloquent doesn't support composite primary keys.

When you check the Eloquent Model class, you can see that the primary key can only be a string, which is used to create the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 34):

Write this line into your Model

`public $primaryKey  = '_id';`

Where _id is your manual primary key

Answer (score 7):

Pretty simple:

```
FaqTrans::where(
            [
                'faq_id' => $faq_id,
                'lang' => $lang
            ]
        )->update(
            [
                'body' => $body,
                'title' => $title
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Nice and easy...!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future (like I did), here's a nice workaround for a composite primary key in Eloquent.

This goes at the top of your model class:

```
protected $primaryKey = array('key1', 'key2');
```

Then you override the `save()` method on your model with this:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    if(!is_array($this->getKeyName()))
        return parent::save($options);

    // Fire Event for others to hook
    if($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false)
        return false;

    // Prepare query for inserting or updating
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();

    // Perform Update
    if ($this->exists) {
        if (count($this->getDirty()) > 0) {
            // Fire Event for others to hook
            if ($this->fireModelEvent('updating') === false)
                return false;

            // Touch the timestamps
            if ($this->timestamps)
                $this->updateTimestamps();

            //
            // START FIX
            //

            // Convert primary key into an array if it's a single value
            $primary = (count($this->getKeyName()) > 1) ? $this->getKeyName() : [$this->getKeyName()];

            // Fetch the primary key(s) values before any changes
            $unique = array_intersect_key($this->original, array_flip($primary));

            // Fetch the primary key(s) values after any changes
            $unique = !empty($unique) ? $unique : array_intersect_key($this->getAttributes(), array_flip($primary));

            // Fetch the element of the array if the array contains only a single element
            $unique = (count($unique) <> 1) ? $unique : reset($unique);

            // Apply SQL logic
            $query->where($unique);

            //
            // END FIX
            //

            // Update the records
            $query->update($this->getDirty());

            // Fire an event for hooking into
            $this->fireModelEvent('updated', false);
        }

    // Perform Insert
    } else {
        // Fire an event for hooking into
        if ($this->fireModelEvent('creating') === false)
            return false;

        // Touch the timestamps
        if ($this->timestamps)
            $this->updateTimestamps();

        // Retrieve the attributes
        $attributes = $this->attributes;

        if ($this->incrementing && !is_array($this->getKeyName()))
            $this->insertAndSetId($query, $attributes);
        else
            $query->insert($attributes);

        // Set exists to true in case someone tries to update it during an event
        $this->exists = true;

        // Fire an event for hooking into
        $this->fireModelEvent('created', false);
    }

    // Fires an event
    $this->fireModelEvent('saved', false);

    // Sync
    $this->original = $this->attributes;

    // Touches all relations
    if (array_get($options, 'touch', true))
        $this->touchOwners();

    return true;
}
```

Original source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517#issuecomment-52996610

**Update 2016-05-03**

My new favorite way to do this:

[How I can put composite keys in models in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/#36995763)

Comment: This does not work in Laravel 8.x.x as it will through an error saying : need string provided array.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `FaqTrans` model and add this.

```
public $key = 'faq_id';
```

That should do it, assuming `faq_id` is more important than the `lang`

Comment: I think it is now $primaryKey according to this: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

Answer (score -2):

If anyone has the same issue. 
I used Nishchit Dhanani answer and it worked pretty well which was:
*Write this line into your Model 
 
 public $primaryKey  = '_id';  
 
Where _id is your manual primary key*

For my case. I had a user table and part of my users are students. So the primary key in my students table was "user_id".  
 
Adding this line in my Student model: public $primaryKey  = 'user_id';

I was able to use the save() method when updating my student object.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just upvote answers you find helpful, rather than writing other answers to repeat them.