# Laravel Model saving data without primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 models: Profile and Student. The profile contains a primary key, **id**. Student model doesn't have any primary key, but one foreign key, **profile_id**, which links to profile.id. I have a function within my Student controller that activates the Student, setting the status from 0 to 1, when called. I am trying to use save() for the update of the value, but unable to do it, prompting me a message as such:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

Can please advise? Thank you very much.

**Student Model:**

```
class Student extends Eloquent {

    protected $primary_key = null;
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'status', 'profile_id');

    public function profile() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
    }
}
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone');

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Student', 'profile_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**StudentController:**

```
public function activate($id) {
        $student = Student::where('profile_id', '=', $id)->first();
        $student->status = 1;
        $student->save();
        return Redirect::to('students');
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to work with this? Eloquent will not anyway, since it depends on the primary key (as any ORM).

Comment: see this https://coderwall.com/p/lhfzia

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You might want to consider adding an `id` field.  It is pretty important to Laravel and packages (for aggregation, specifically)

but if you must...

**Student Model:** (camel case `primaryKey` property)

```
class Student extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;


    protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'status', 'profile_id');

    public function profile() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right about the "primaryKey", but upon trying to change it in the code, I got a loading issue upon calling the function instead. I am not sure is it really the case that I definitely require an id field to work, even though it doesn't serve any purpose in my case, but just to satisfy the requirement for needing a primary key.

Comment: What is the loading issue you are experiencing after changing the property name?  No doubt, you can use this table with Laravel and no primary key, but it may become increasingly difficult when trying to integrate other packages: `Cruddy` for example.  Adding a `primary key` may save you some headache down the road and i can't think of any case where it would be costly.

Comment: Thanks, the page just doesn't load, and firefox states connection reset. I dig into the laravel.log, doesn't show any error. But I am going ahead and work with adding the Id, which may become handy next time.

Comment: @jl. did you start your webserver?

Comment: Note, that official documentation doesn't mention about such case and in some reasons it can lead to unexpected errors, hard to locate and debug, so **I strongly recommend everyone don't do this!**

Comment: I can confirm that setting the `$primaryKey` to `null` just makes Laravel blow up and give a white screen of death with absolutely no logging anywhere, any time an update is attempted. This will work for inserts, but not updates.

Comment: Confirmed, stuff super easy, when working with db directly, is super-duper complicated in Laravel. Laravel NEEDS primary key. Without it entire framework collapses silly and is totally useless. So, design your DB with primary keys, or use some other framework, as Laravel is useless to you.

Comment: Worth noting, if you're not using autoIncrement and instead are using UUID or something similar, make sure you sent `$incrementing = false` in the model

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and couldn't use a primary key field for this table.

Since Eloquent cannot update tables like this, I solved it simply deciding updating the row in a different way:

```
NameOfMyTable::where('entity_type', 1)->update(['last_import' => Carbon::now()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is somewhat old, I think I can contribute something.

Using models without a primary key is not something to be promoted: WHENEVER POSSIBLE YOU SHOULD ADD A PRIMARY KEY.

Having said the above, I will explain how to handle these situations where the model does not have a primary key, either due to a design flaw or because the model itself does not represent an entity but a relationship between two or more entities. For example, the pivot tables.

The correct way is to override the setKeysForSaveQuery method of the Model class, in the model that has no primary key. This allows you to modify the id = $id condition that Laravel tries to do by default.

Let's see:

```php
class Student extends Eloquent
{
     protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'status', 'profile_id'];

     public function profile()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
     }

     /**
      * Set the keys for a select query.
      *
      * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
      */
     protected function setKeysForSelectQuery($query)
     {
         $query->where('profile_id', '=', $this->profile_id);
     }
}
```

I must clarify that it is not really a trick, Laravel actually does it in the case of pivot tables.

Obviously I give this answer for cases where there really is no primary key or the update condition involves a combination of columns. In this question it could well be assumed that profile_id is the primary key since the relationship student:profile is one to one, let's see:

```php
class Student extends Eloquent
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'profile_id';
     public $incrementing = false;

     protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'status', 'profile_id'];

     public function profile()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone has the same issue, I used [Nishchit Dhanani answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654938/243925) and it worked pretty well:

Write this line into your Model:

```
public $primaryKey = '_id';
```

Where `_id` is your manual primary key.

For my case I had a user table and part of my users are students. So the primary key in my students table was "user_id" and I added this line in my `Student` model:

```
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

I was able to use the `save()` method when updating my student object.

In your case you would just need to add this to your student model:

```
public $primaryKey = 'profile_id';
```